# Why it's funny when a husband says he is thankful to have someone he enjoys being quarantined with and the wife says it must be nice?

Tags: jokes

Why it's funny when a husband says he is thankful to have someone he enjoys being quarantined with and his wife says it must be nice (sorry about the long title). Thank you!

[image]

Comment: The wife's answer implies she doesn't enjoy being quarantined with the husband. But I don't see how this is a question about the English language.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about analysis of a text rather than language or usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He likes being with her. She doesn't like being with him.

Comment: Another interpretation is that they aren't quarantined together.

Comment: Do we know if they are quarantined together or is he talking about being with someone else? And yes this is analysis but is not too far off the mark to be here.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations - I thought I asked the question on the forum that relate to jokes ... sorry.